# ¿Cómo se hace Hot Reload en Blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

¿Existe alguna manera de aplicar el concepto de "Hot Reloading" en el proceso de desarrollo usando Blazor? Es decir, en vez de estar dando F5 en cada cambio realizado, ¿se puede hacer de manera automática?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se realiza ejecutando el siguiente código:

```
dotnet watch run debug
```

Ahora sí, a seguir desarrollando con todo el power!!!